# Using SCSS scoped in Blade like Vue components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sass, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 8 and Vue.js together. So I'm developing a website with Blade and Vue components.
I want something to add scss code in a specific Blade template. Exactly like a Vue component:

```
// Vue component example
<template>
...
</template>
<script>
...
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
// SCSS codes scoped here
</style>
```

I want something exactly like `<style lang="scss" scoped>` in Blade.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use blade `@stack` and `@push`

in `layout.blade.php`

```php
@stack('css')
```

in specific.blade.php

```php
@push('css')
<style>
</style>
@endpush
```

like this when `specific.blade.php` will load then only that css will load in layout which is same as `vue scoped`

ref link
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks

Comment: Thanks bro, I'm using `@push` directive. However I want SCSS lang in blade. Compiling SCSS code in a separate file `app.scss` would take lots of time to be compiled. Thanks anyway.

Comment: use css if it is in temple css

Comment: @KamleshPaul this does not become `scoped`, it simply adds whatever specific css to the stack which is global.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in a simular situation. I'm not aware of this being possible without a lot of work (on the blade compiler side). Having `<style lang="scss" scoped>` in blade would require scss compilation and scoping. A simpler solution would be as Kamlesh suggested, supplying the style in the template.

Something that does come close as well albeit without scss compilation is having the ability to write multiple `vue single file component`-like components in your blade templates. Vue does not provide this ability (as elegantly as with vue files imho), but with a layer called [vue blocks](https://github.com/j-angnoe/vue-blocks) you may achieve the following:

```html
<template component="some-component">
    <div>
        <p>My paragraph</p>
        <div class="some block"></div>
    </div>
    <style scoped>
        :root { 
            background: black;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        p {
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .block {
            border: 3px solid green;
            height: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    // vue component here
    export default { 
       data() { return { } },
       mounted() { 

       }
    }
    </script>
</template>
```

More information can be found here:

- https://fluxfx.nl/vue-blocks/examples/index.html#/features/scoped-styles

Comment: It's a good idea to have Vue components. I have them. But I want to use this in Blade for some reasons. Unfortunately compiling **SCSS** files would take a lot of time, and every time I want to see the changes I would be waiting for that. In Vue components it is vice versa and takes no time to be compiled. I guess this is because of its **Virtual DOM handler**.

Comment: Allright I understand, you are not looking for writing vue components in blade, you'd just like to be able to write scoped scss in blade, instead of having one big app.scss file that takes a while to generate. I can see why you'd want that.